# Error during reading json in Aurelia.io example

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp, aurelia

I'm extending aurelia's [get started app](http://aurelia.io/get-started.html) by adding custom moduls.
I've got an error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" while reading a json. But json validator doesn't find any errors.

Here is my json 
    `{
      "news": [
        {
          "title": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text",
          "type": "news",
          "tags": [
            "news",
            "fish",
            "loremipsumdolor"
          ],
          "text": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry."
        },
        {
          "title": "Lorem Ipsum",
          "type": "news",
          "tags": [
            "news",
            "fish"
          ],
          "text": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s."
        }
      ]
    }`

And here is my module that tries to load that json (basically it's a copy-paste from flickr.js which can be found in example code)
`
    import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
    import {HttpClient} from 'aurelia-http-client';

```
@inject(HttpClient)
export class News{
  heading = 'News';
  items = [];
  url = '/res/data.json';

  constructor(http){
    this.http = http;
  }

  activate(){
    debugger;
    return this.http.jsonp(this.url).then(response => {
      this.items = response.content.news;
    });
  }

  canDeactivate(){
    return confirm('Are you sure you want to leave?');
  }
}
```

'
When example code is executed it loads json from flikr and wraps it in jsonp_callback_92661(). That's the only difference. May it be the root of my problem?

Comment: If you try to print response.content, then what do you get ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that's the root of your problem. You are using `jsonp` when you don't really need it. Since you are serving a static json file yourself, and presumably served over the same domain the main app lives, you don't need to use jsonp. [Good explanations about jsonp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about) are here in SO if you are not already familiar (flicker wraps the response in a function call because that's needed for jsonp to work).

You should be able to use `get`:

```
return this.http.get(this.url).then(response => {
  //not sure if response.content is an object already.
  //you may need to JSON.parse response.content
  this.items = response.content.news;
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm not familiar with jsonp, so I thought it would be okay to use a static json without wrapping it.